# Despite my eventlistener, my function will still run regardless

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a game and a form that gets information from the user via an input.
I would like my function that starts the game to run after the user places an input and clicks my
"play game" button, but the function that starts the game will run regardless of whether or not the button is pressed. Thanks.

```
"use strict";

window.onload = main;



function main()
{

    var symbolAmount = 0;

    document.getElementById("numSymbols").value = symbolAmount;

    //symbolAmount cannot be greater than 8
    if (symbolAmount > 8)
    {
        symbolAmount = 8;
    }

    document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener("click", startGame(symbolAmount));

}


function startGame(symbolAmount)
{
    //getting rid of the startup form
    

    //symbols array being loaded and the various variables for the table setup
    var symbols = new Array("!", "@", "#", "$", ";", "+", "*", "&");
    var gameHtmlInfo = "<table id= 'gameTable' \
    style= \
    'width:60%; \
    margin-left:20%:\
    max-height:60%; \
       '>";


    var columnCount;    
    var rowCount;

    //setting the columns and rows for the table 
    if ((symbolAmount*2 === 4) || (symbolAmount*2 === 16))
    {
        columnCount = (symbolAmount/2);
        rowCount = (symbolAmount/2);
    }
    else 
    {
        columnCount = symbolAmount;
        rowCount = 2;
    }

    //making the tables

    for(var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        gameHtmlInfo += "<tr class='rows'>";
        //making the cells
        for(var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
        {
            gameHtmlInfo += "<td class='card'>" + symbols[j] + "</td>";
            symbols.shift();
        }


        gameHtmlInfo += "</tr>";
    }

    gameHtmlInfo += "</table>";


}
```

Comment: `addEventListener` requires you to pass a *function*, not a ***function call***.

Answer (score 1):

You actually call the `startGame` function when registering the event. Try wrapping the function with either [arrow-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) or just a normal funcion:

```js
document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener("click", () => startGame(symbolAmount));
```

This pattern is also known as [Curry](https://javascript.info/currying-partials).

Comment: While you're right you might want to add a link to documentation for arrow functions. "Try this" is rarely helpful without an explanation.

Comment: thanks this worked.  Please, what is the name of the "() =>" so i can learn more about it

Comment: `()=>` arrow-functions. It is a shorthand for defining functions, regardless they do not bind `this` on its own and use the parent closure (`this`) instead. There is nothing special to using arrow-functions here.  `document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener("click", functions(){ startGame(symbolAmount)} );`  woks as well.

Answer (score 0):

The curent code immediately invokes your `startGame` function as you create a subscription to the click event of your button.

change your function to return a callback like so.

```
function startGame(symbolAmount) {
  return function () {
    //getting rid of the startup form


    //symbols array being loaded and the various variables for the table setup
    var symbols = new Array("!", "@", "#", "$", ";", "+", "*", "&");
    var gameHtmlInfo = "<table id= 'gameTable' \
    style= \
    'width:60%; \
    margin-left:20%:\
    max-height:60%; \
       '>";


    var columnCount;
    var rowCount;

    //setting the columns and rows for the table 
    if ((symbolAmount * 2 === 4) || (symbolAmount * 2 === 16)) {
      columnCount = (symbolAmount / 2);
      rowCount = (symbolAmount / 2);
    }
    else {
      columnCount = symbolAmount;
      rowCount = 2;
    }

    //making the tables

    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      gameHtmlInfo += "<tr class='rows'>";
      //making the cells
      for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
        gameHtmlInfo += "<td class='card'>" + symbols[j] + "</td>";
        symbols.shift();
      }


      gameHtmlInfo += "</tr>";
    }

    gameHtmlInfo += "</table>";

  }

}
```

Comment: thanks this worked, I guess I don't understand functions so well i'll have to do some review. I didn't know that in my context i needed a return.

Comment: There's a first time for everything. :) Keep it up Never giveup!